# Where to change the value of SleepSpoutWaitStrategyTime

Tags: apache-storm

I am using storm... I want to increase the time of `topology.sleep.spout.wait.strategy.time.ms` from 1 milliseconds(default) to 1 second. But I don't know where this is located. I have a config class where it is defined as follows

```
public static final String TOPOLOGY_SLEEP_SPOUT_WAIT_STRATEGY_TIME_MS="topology.sleep.spout.wait.strategy.time.ms";
```

and I want to include this field under a bean whose class is `backtype.storm.config`

What parameter name should I be using? Is it `emptyEmit`?

EDIT:
I searched the net and it is specified that the values will be present in `default.yaml`, but I couldn't find such file in Eclipse.

Can someone help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can specify it in the `storm.yaml` file.

`default.yaml` is just a default `storm.yaml` file used to supply default values when you don't override them.

Answer (score 3):

...
conf.put(Config.TOPOLOGY_SLEEP_SPOUT_WAIT_STRATEGY_TIME_MS, 1000);
...
cluster.submitTopology("xyz", conf, buildTopology());

Answer (score 2):

change `topology.sleep.spout.wait.strategy.time.ms` property in storm's default.yaml file located in the `$STORM_ROOT_DIR/conf` dir

> but I couldn't find such file in Eclipse.

It should be included in the storm's jar ... for example if you are using `0.9.0-wip21` distribution then the default.yaml file should be found under the `storm-core-0.9.0-wip21.jar